# Flux visibility problems with volatile variable

Tags: java, multithreading, project-reactor

I have a simple Spring controller which have a Spring service as dependency.
In the service class I have a static volatile field of type int called flag.
When I invoke createFlux() method through my controller, the flag is set to 5 and then a new Flux is created, which checks the flag every second, and prints a message based on the flag value. Because of the delayElements method semantics the code will be executed in parallel. And after that if I invoke the changeFlag() method, which changes the value of the flag, and because the flag variable is volatile I expect the message which is printed to change but that is not happening.

Here is the code:

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

  @Autowired private MyService myService;

  @GetMapping("createFlux")
  public void createFlux() {
    myService.createFlux();
  }

  @GetMapping("changeFlag")
  public void changeFlag() {
    myService.changeFlag();
  }
}


@Service
public class MyService {

  private static volatile int flag = 3;

  public void changeFlag() {
    flag = 3;
    System.out.println("############# Flag = " + flag);
  }

  public void createFlux() {
    flag = 5;
    System.out.println("Flag = " + flag);

    Flux.generate(sink -> {
      if (flag == 3) {
        sink.next("Stop");
      } else {
        sink.next("Start");
      }
    }).delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1)).subscribe(s -> System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " : " + s));
  }
}
```

And this is the output in the console:

```
Flag = 5
parallel-1 : Start
parallel-2 : Start
parallel-3 : Start
parallel-4 : Start
############# Flag = 3
parallel-5 : Start
parallel-6 : Start
parallel-7 : Start
parallel-8 : Start
parallel-1 : Start
parallel-2 : Start
parallel-3 : Start
parallel-4 : Start
parallel-5 : Start
parallel-6 : Start
parallel-7 : Start
parallel-8 : Start
parallel-1 : Start
parallel-2 : Start
parallel-3 : Start
parallel-4 : Start
parallel-5 : Start
parallel-6 : Start
parallel-7 : Start
parallel-8 : Start
parallel-1 : Start
parallel-2 : Start
parallel-3 : Start
parallel-4 : Start
parallel-5 : Start
parallel-6 : Start
parallel-7 : Start
parallel-8 : Start
parallel-1 : Stop
parallel-2 : Stop
parallel-3 : Stop
parallel-4 : Stop
parallel-5 : Stop
parallel-6 : Stop
```

From the output it can be seen that it keeps printing the message Start even when the value of flag is changed to 3. And after a while the printed message is changed. I suppose that there is some caching or something like that, but the volatile variables are not cached.

The question is - is this a bug or I'm missing something?

Comment: Can you try making this variable an instance variable and see if output changes?

Comment: No change. No matter if it is static or not the result is the same.

Comment: Can you change from int to Integer and try again?

Comment: Still no change. It doesn't make sense to work with Integer, but not with int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The generate consumer is executed instantly for a bunch of elements. You can easily confirm that by adding a log right after the `generate`:

```java
    Flux.generate(...).doOnNext(e -> log.info("executed: {}", e))
```

Prints:

```
2022-01-20 13:31:50,346  INFO parallel-1  - Flag = 5
2022-01-20 13:31:50,349  INFO parallel-1  - executed: Start
2022-01-20 13:31:50,351  INFO parallel-1  - executed: Start
2022-01-20 13:31:50,351  INFO parallel-1  - executed: Start
2022-01-20 13:31:50,351  INFO parallel-1  - executed: Start
2022-01-20 13:31:50,351  INFO parallel-1  - executed: Start
2022-01-20 13:31:50,351  INFO parallel-1  - executed: Start
2022-01-20 13:31:50,351  INFO parallel-1  - executed: Start
2022-01-20 13:31:50,351  INFO parallel-1  - executed: Start
2022-01-20 13:31:50,351  INFO parallel-1  - executed: Start
2022-01-20 13:31:50,351  INFO parallel-1  - executed: Start
2022-01-20 13:31:50,351  INFO parallel-1  - executed: Start
2022-01-20 13:31:50,351  INFO parallel-1  - executed: Start
2022-01-20 13:31:50,351  INFO parallel-1  - executed: Start
2022-01-20 13:31:50,351  INFO parallel-1  - executed: Start
2022-01-20 13:31:50,351  INFO parallel-1  - executed: Start
2022-01-20 13:31:50,351  INFO parallel-1  - executed: Start
2022-01-20 13:31:50,351  INFO parallel-1  - executed: Start
2022-01-20 13:31:50,351  INFO parallel-1  - executed: Start
2022-01-20 13:31:50,351  INFO parallel-1  - executed: Start
2022-01-20 13:31:50,351  INFO parallel-1  - executed: Start
2022-01-20 13:31:50,351  INFO parallel-1  - executed: Start
2022-01-20 13:31:50,351  INFO parallel-1  - executed: Start
2022-01-20 13:31:50,351  INFO parallel-1  - executed: Start
2022-01-20 13:31:50,351  INFO parallel-1  - executed: Start
2022-01-20 13:31:50,351  INFO parallel-1  - executed: Start
2022-01-20 13:31:50,351  INFO parallel-1  - executed: Start
2022-01-20 13:31:50,351  INFO parallel-1  - executed: Start
2022-01-20 13:31:50,351  INFO parallel-1  - executed: Start
2022-01-20 13:31:50,352  INFO parallel-1  - executed: Start
2022-01-20 13:31:50,352  INFO parallel-1  - executed: Start
2022-01-20 13:31:50,352  INFO parallel-1  - executed: Start
2022-01-20 13:31:50,352  INFO parallel-1  - executed: Start
```

`generate` method emits elements based on the demand from the downstream. It generates 32 elements first and buffers them. As and when downstream starts processing elements and when the buffer size drops the below threshold, it emits a few more elements.

Comment: That's right. I could even debug it. Thank you :)